# Sscanf problem and reading from command-line

Tags: c, command-line, segmentation-fault, scanf

Hello hahah yet again.
C- Unix
Im reading something like this:

a.out [23+10i]

```
sscanf(argv[count], "[%d%c%di]", &a, &operand1, &b);
```

I want to separate as follows:
a=23
b=10
operand='+'
but im getting that segfault(core dumped) error, what am I doing wrong?

By the way, thanks alot for answering all my silly questions

Comment: What is the value of `count`?  What are the declarations of `a`, `operand1` and `b`?

Comment: Tough to say, but print out argv[count] to make sure it's the argument you want.

Comment: `[` is a shell metacharacter and could be causing your arguments to not be what you think they are.  Do you get the same result if you put quotes around your argument like this: `./a.out "[23+10i]"`?

Comment: @Adam nope, even with quotes it keeps bringing up segfault.
count is =1 and Im printing it out.
>$ a.out "[23+45i]"
The command line has 1 arguments:
1:[23+45i]
Segmentation Fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a, b;
    char operand1;
    int n;

    printf("scanning argv[argc - 1]: %s\n", argv[argc - 1]);
    /* It works for me */
    n = sscanf(argv[argc - 1], "[%d%c%di]", &a, &operand1, &b);

    printf("%d values read\n", n);
    if (n != 3) printf("there was an error in scanf ...\n");
    printf("The values were %d, %c, and %d\n", a, operand1, b);
    return 0;
}
```

And a sample run:

```
$ ./a.out [23+43i]
scanning argv[argc - 1]: [23+43i]
3 values read
The values were 23, +, and 43
```

**Note that `argv[argc]` is a NULL pointer.**